# How to make with twitter bootstrap tabs a navigation bar similar to http://www.myntra.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do i create a navigation bar like the one in " http://www.myntra.com " where on hovering over the "men" tab a div is shown and on moving the mouse pointer outside the div goes off. I tried using the tabs in the bootstrap 3.

```
   <div role="tabpanel">
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">.qqq..</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">..aaa.</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">.vvv..</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">.zzz..</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

and this jquery code below to make it look like the navigation bar myntra.com.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $('.nav-tabs > li > a').hover( function(){
                $(this).tab('show');
            });
        });
```

CSS code :

```
.tab-pane{
border: 1px solid black;
z-index: 10;
position: absolute;
width: 84%;
height: 50%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

}

Where should i make changes to give the same feel as the navigation bar in www.myntra.com ? Or is there any other approach to achieve it ? Please help me on this.

Comment: Just look at their code copy the div.pane-cnt with it's content and see. It's just a link element changing the index in the data-index attribute and then showing the corresponding div with the same index. Check out the Amazon Menu http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown

Comment: Are you copying their CSS , Structure ?? Its Illegal to steal without permission !

Comment: No i am not copying anything from them. I am aware of that.I just quoted them as an example site. Have seen many ecommerce sites having such kind of div dropdowns on hover.I am just curious to know how it works.Thank you.